# Create object at runtime based on SqlQuery executed

Tags: c#, reflection, ado.net

The overall objective is to get a Json representation of the query results of the SqlQuery executed. This Json will be used to create visualizations/reports on the browser using js based charting tools.

Now, controls like gridview are able to read the column names as well as the data and give us an html representation of the data. So I think it should be possible to write code such that it can read from a sql data reader and come up with a json representation.

I could not find anything in my searches which does what I want. How do I go about doing this? any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an SqlDataAdapter to fill a DataSet. [This blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/navaidakhtar/archive/2008/07/08/converting-data-table-dataset-into-json-string.aspx) describes a way of converting a DataTable or DataSet into its JSON representation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Json.Net serializer. It supports serializing a `Dictionary<string,object>` to a JSON object.
Another big shot would be using NHibernate and serializing the resulting objects.

[Here is another link to using the Json.Net serializer for DataSets:](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Sep/03/DataTable-JSON-Serialization-in-JSONNET-and-JavaScriptSerializer)

If you scroll down to the comments on this page you see a much shorter solution using the Dictionary approach.